# If $f$ is harmonic on $G$ and $f\big|_U=0,$ then $f\equiv0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $G\subset\mathbb C$ be a connected open set, and let $f:G\to\mathbb R$ be harmonic. If there is an nonempty open set $U\subset G$ s.t. $f\big|_U=0$ then $f\equiv0.$

In the proof $N:=\{z\in G:\exists V(z)\subset G\ \text{with}\ f\big|_V=0\}$ is nonempty and open and closed at the same time, so it must be equal to $G$

It is clear that $N$ is open but why closed? If I assume that $z_{\infty}$ is an accumulation point of a sequence $\{z_n\}_n$ in $N$, then in the open disc $D_r(z_{\infty})$, $f$ is a real part of a holomorphic function, say $g$ but in the disc except $z_{\infty}$, $g$ has real part $0$, can I apply Morera to conclude that $\Re(g)$ is $0$ in the whole disc ?

Comment: Not Morera. The identity theorem tells you that $g$ is constant.